# Can Rapidminer extract an XPath value from a Specific list of URLs?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler, rapidminer

I've been playing around with Rapidminer and can't quite seem to figure this out. I have a huge list of URLs listed in an excel file and would like to extract a single XPath element from each URL. Is there anyway I could do this with Rapidminer?

I've seen the tutorials Neil Mcguigan, but they seem to crawl the web/site in general rather than from a specific set of URLs.

Comment: Looks a pretty similar question to the one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045024/can-rapidminer-extract-xpaths-from-a-list-of-urls-instead-of-first-saving-the-h).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [Apache Nutch](https://nutch.apache.org/), [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) and similar web crawling tools.

You may just be looking at the wrong tools for this job: you want to *scrape* data from web sites, not do actual "data mining" (which is more of a heuristic statistical analysis).

[Nutch](https://nutch.apache.org/) (Java) and [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) (Python) are platforms for developing custom web crawlers and doing web scraping.